# Write XmlReader XML to immediate window in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-debugging, xmlreader

How can the `XML` contained in an `XmlReader` instance be written to the immediate window in Visual Studio?  Seems like `ToString()` would do the trick, but it doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
reader.MoveToContent();
reader.ReadOuterXml();
```

But be aware that the XmlReader will not be usable any more.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to debug XmlReader? From my experience it's easier to give up.

Dispite that you can call `XDocument.Load(reader).ToString()` what will read the reader to its end thus make it further unusable. However you can initialize a new reader from resulting document. To make it easier write a helper method.